ansible expect module does not create the file with creates option
I have the below task
- name: "PATCH| 1.5.2 | Ensure bootloader password is set"
  ansible.builtin.expect:
    command: grub2-setpassword
    responses:
      Enter password: "{{ grub_password }}"
      Confirm password: "{{ grub_password }}"
    creates: /boot/grub2/user.cfg
  notify: grub2-mkconfig
  no_log: true
  tags: 
    - fix

when I run the task the password is set but the file is not created. I have checked multiple issue with expect module but I don't see any that touch on the creates option. I tried different servers and got the same thing. without the creates option the password is set as well. Any help in troubleshooting why the file isn't being created will be appreciated.

Take a look at the documentation for the creates option: "A filename, when it already exists, this step will not be run." It makes the task conditional on whether or not the file exists; it does not create the file.

you are correct @larsks; but it is still not clear to me still. are you saying the task only run if that file exist? My understanding at first was that if the file already exist it will not create it but if it doesn't , it will create. Thanks for your input!

If the file exists, then the task will not be run.

I see. Thanks for the clarification. It is confusing when we all know that create in ansible always create a file if it doesn't exist. I don't see the use for that option if that is all it does. Thanks for your help.

It is confusing when we all know that create in ansible always create a file if it doesn't exist <= All commands I know using the creates option work exactly the same way (i.e. don't run if that file you are suppose to create already exists), like for example command, shell, unarchive, script...

@Zeitounator I get that part; but in my case the bootloader password was set but no file was created(which is how it is supposed to work explained to me by  @larsks. What I found confusing what the  similarity between create and creates and the nuance in what they actually do. Thanks for you input!

Try this one instead

name: "PATCH| 1.5.2 | Ensure bootloader password is set"
ansible.builtin.expect:
command: grub2-setpassword
responses:
Enter password: "{{ grub_password }}"
Confirm password: "{{ grub_password }}"
changed_when: true
notify: grub2-mkconfig
no_log: true
tags:

fix




As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
